# Is it possible to push to a nuget repository without ssl Verify?

Tags: ssl, nuget, nexus

I want to push to an internal (inside the LAN) nuget repository (hosted on Nexus version 3) from a Windows 2012 R2 server. Is it possible to push to this repository and ignore ssl verification like you can with git push?

for example with git you can do `git config http.sslVerify false`, can a similar thing be done with `nuget push` command? I had a Google but nothing came up.

My nuget command is:

`nuget push my.nuget.package.version.nupkg -Source https://nexus.repo.local/repo -apikey {apikey}`

I currently get this error: `The remote certificate is invalid according to the validation procedure.`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I haven't found a way to do what you want (boy would I like to), but if you can install a self-signed cert with your own CA, you can install that CA as trusted on the client to circumvent the issue.